# What can cause a timeout getting SQL connection from pool?

Tags: c#, iis-7, sql-server-2012

I have a web app deployed under IIS.  It's been getting timeout errors, and I believe I've tracked the problem down to code that doesn't properly dispose of SQL connections.

This will require quite a lot of surgery to fix, so at least until I can finish implementing and testing the new code, using `using` blocks correctly, I decided to bump up the connection pool size to something astronomical.  But that doesn't seem to have helped.  My connection string is:

> Data Source=MyServer;Initial Catalog=MyDb;User ID=MyUser;Password=MyPwd;Max Pool Size=10000

And my log file shows:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.

I have been keeping Performance Monitor open over this period, and the number of user connections maxed out at around 150.  So I don't think it can be that we're running out of connections.

What else could be causing this error?

Comment: You probably _are_ maxing out on connections - probably on the _server_ side. You really need to make sure connections get closed and only stay open as little as possible.

Comment: @Oded - I thought SQL server could support up to 32,768 connections?  Or was I dreaming?

Comment: AFAIK, if you configure it (server and database)

Comment: @Shaul:- Please check wherever you have specified the connection setting the timeout field???"integrated security=SSPI;SERVER=YOUR_SERVER;DATABASE=YOUR_DB_NAME;Min Pool Size=5;Max Pool Size=10000;Connect Timeout=60;"

Comment: @RahulTripathi - I think I know what you're getting at, that the connection pool requires the connection strings to be identical.  But if they're not identical, that would just result in *more* connection pools, not *fewer*, wouldn't it?

Comment: @Oded, my server is configured to "0" maximum concurrent connections.  Is there some other setting I need to change?

Comment: Why don't you think that you *did* hit the limit? You even say that perfmon showed 150 connections in use, which is probably your configured maximum.

Comment: SQL Server does not need to be configured for the max amount of connections. Also, if it was rejecting them you would get a different message.

Comment: @usr - per the question, my connection string is set to allow 10,000 connections.  Is there some other setting I have to change?

Comment: Ok I understand now. Can you show what perfmon counter you used? The error should indeed not occur. Can you open 10 connections in a loop and confirm that the counter tracks them? How many connections can you open in a loop?

Comment: @usr, I was using both the "user connections" and "logical connections" counters (not sure what the difference is; they consistently read the same number).  In any case, I think this question is becoming moot; I've fixed up the code to use `using` blocks, and hopefully that will solve the real problem.  Still, I'd love to know what the problem was here...

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately SqlCommand does not obey ConnectionString or SqlConnection's time-out. And it has to be set manually. It's because the time-out mentioned in connection string is used for connecting, not executing. So that please consider setting up it's time-out by code.

```
var conn = new SqlConnection(cs);
var cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandTimeout = conn.ConnectionTimeout;
...
```